# Parsing data in Excel using python

Tags: python, excel, parsing

In Excel, I have to separate the following value from one cell into two:

```
2016-12-12 (r=0.1)
2016-12-13* (r=0.7)
```

How do I do that in Python so that in the Excel file, dates and "r=#" will be in different cells? And also, is there a way to automatically remove the "*" sign?

Comment: Can you save it as a .csv instead?

Comment: This is three or four questions in one post.

Answer (score 0):

This task is pretty straight forward if you use pandas:

**Build a test file:**

```
import pandas as pd
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    ['2016-12-12 (r=0.1)', '2016-12-13* (r=0.7)'], columns=['data'])
df_out.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

**Code to convert string:**

```
def convert_date(row):
    return pd.Series([c.strip('*').strip('(').strip(')')
                      for c in row.split()])
```

**Test code:**

```
# read in test file
df_in = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
print(df_in)

# build a new dataframe
df_new = df_in['data'].apply(convert_date)
df_new.columns = ['date', 'r']
print(df_new)

# save the dataframe
df_new.to_excel('test2.xlsx')
```

**Results:**

```
                  data
0   2016-12-12 (r=0.1)
1  2016-12-13* (r=0.7)

         date      r
0  2016-12-12  r=0.1
1  2016-12-13  r=0.7
```